# Meteor http call and character encoding

Tags: javascript, meteor

The following code returns some weird characters like � instead of é:

```
var html = HTTP.get(url);
console.log(html);
```

The encoding of the url page is ISO-8859-1 and I guess HTTP.get() expect UTF-8.
How do I tell HTTP.get to except ISO-8859-1 for this specific url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, HTTP doesn't accept encoding convertion. It seems that it is because of the isomorphism of the package : in the browser you cannot convert chars. 
So i did a little plugin that will add an extra method to HTTP package, but only for the server : https://atmospherejs.com/rebolon/http-plugin-encoding
The new method is HTTP.getWithEncoding(url, {"encoding: {'from': 'iso-8859-15', 'to': 'iso-8859-1'}}, [callback]);

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But I get  "Error: Encoding not recognized: 'iso-8859' (searched as: 'iso8859')" with your package

Comment: try ISO-8859-1.  The plugin use iconv-lite, so you can lLook at iconv-lite npm package for more information.

Comment: Well, instead of having �, now it's Ã©. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> is on the top of the page, so it should be the right encoding or am I missing something?

Comment: try to identify the right encoding from the source file, then do the conversion. You could also try directly with iconv-lite inside a nodejs script. If you have the same problem, contact me directly by mail and send me the source file, and we will update this flow when everything will be resolved

Comment: Well, here is the page I tried to crawl: http://www.lexpress.fr/rss/alaune.xml Thanks for your help. I tried with iconv-light, I got the same result.

Comment: ok, i did a successful try this night with that encoding config {'from': 'iso-8859-15', 'to': 'iso-8859-1'}
Tell me if it's right. I have to test my package on a new VM to check if Npm and meteor works well without meteorhacks:npm

Comment: It works. Thanks. Can I ask how did you find out {'from': 'iso-8859-15', 'to': 'iso-8859-1'}?

Comment: Just because i already use it on another website :-) so i tryed. Notepad++ identify the file as iso-8859-1 so i decided to check all variant.